# How to use a single bitmap as a multiple mask for another bitmap?

Tags: android, android-canvas, android-bitmap

I have an original image and a mask image that has different colors for different regions of the original image. I want to let user see only the part of the original image that he tapped. End goal is to let users to paint the original image part by part by tapping each part.

Currently I am doing this with floodfill however it is very inefficient for undo redo operations. I was wondering if I could do this with BitmapShader and PorterDuffModes without creating hundreds of small bitmaps as seperate mask bitmaps.

[image]
[image]